# iPhone transition effect to reveal an updated version of the same view

Tags: iphone, transition

So I have an app on the main page is details of the current date.
The page has left and right buttons to move to previous and next dates and a table of info below. This all works.

However I want to add a swipe between the days, now doing the swipe control is easy and I have done that.

However I want to give the visual indication of a swipe.
I am not changes views , I am simply refreshing the current view.

If you look at myfitnesspal (free app) , that swipes between dates in the same way I am after.

It scrolls off (a copy?) of the screen to one side , slides in the latest version to replace it.

I am at a loss on how to achieve such a simple effect without going for multiple views which unless I am misunderstanding would be over complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIPageControl, here is a tutorial of how to implement one using only two views:  [Cocoa with Love UIPageControl sample](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

Both views can be identical, (instances of the same Class, created programmatically or 2 CustomView outlets on IB)

This way you only need to update the view that's going to slide in the screen.

Comment: Sorry don't quite follow this. How will hiding it and then doing an animation to show it again give the impression of the initial view wiping off ?